# macbookair 2014-15 model yosemite macos 10.10.5 external DELL HDMI monitor sound and brightness control

Tags: display, audio

I need to control brightness and sound volume in external monitor DELL 2420HS connected thru HDMI cable from thunderbolt port. I downloaded [MonitorControl](https://github.com/MonitorControl/MonitorControl). image (dmg file) is showing 'corrupt image' when trying to open. Tried all versions starting 2.0.0...1.7.1, 1.7.0, thru to 1.5. The same error message. Please help.

Comment: Tried with 2.0.0, worked here. How did you download the DMG?

Answer (score 1):

Minimum OS requirement, according to the [github page](https://github.com/MonitorControl/MonitorControl), is Sierra, macOS 10.12

A MacBook Air from 2014 is [perfectly capable](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i5-1.4-13-early-2014-specs.html) of running 10.15, Catalina.

Comment: Hmm, I read the question as "I can't open the downloaded DMG file", not as "it's not compatible with the macOS I'm running".

Comment: @nohillside - me too, tbh; though whether that's because of a format incompatibility or actual corrupt download seems moot… it won't work even if you can open it.

Comment: Ah, missed the OS version in the question title.